# how to remove error "* Item qty declaration error."

Tags: cart, error

I’m getting this message while adding a product to the cart. “* Item qty declaration error.“ any ideas how to fix that ? Thanks.
[image: error qty]

Comment: update your code for adding product to cart.

Comment: i use default code. i see error display in cart page(checkout/cart). Can you explain error, i don't know what happen with error, why it occur. Thanks

Comment: update full error message...

Comment: i upload picture for error

Comment: its looks like js error.not PHP..confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens during the function `checkData` on a quote item.

```
    try {
        $this->setQty($qty);
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e){
        $this->setHasError(true);
        $this->setMessage($e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $this->setHasError(true);
        $this->setMessage(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Item qty declaration error.'));
    }
```

It happens when a generic `Exception` is caught. I would suggest that you need to dig deeper into the exception to find out the problem. Make sure you have logging and developer mode set-up and you could even update the code to simply `Mage::log($e->getMessage())` to see what is going on with the error. Another great tool for debugging this would be xdebug.