# Magento 2 - Item qty declaration error

Tags: magento2.2

I am running Magento 2.2.0 and this error has started showing up for different products.  It doesn't stop the user from checking out, it just shows this message.  I found another post for Magento 1.9 that it is caused by a general exception ([how to remove error "* Item qty declaration error."](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49298/how-to-remove-error-item-qty-declaration-error)) but I cannot find any information on how to fix it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please post full error and look into var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log if you more logs regarding this error.

Comment: @Vivek - that is the full error - Item qty declaration error.  It shows on the item page and when I view the basket.  I had looked in the system log and there was a warning for batch size and no other warnings.  In the exception log -  "main.CRITICAL: URL key for specified store already exists" but that was it.  This error seems to only show up for me if there isn't a configurable item in the cart.  If I view the basket and remove the configurable item the error shows up.